# How to make a Please wait page between 2 JSP's

Tags: jsp

How to make a Please wait page between 2 JSP's.do we have to use javascript.then will it not be browser specific?

Comment: `setTimeout()` javascript function.

Comment: Hi Monica, Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript or jquery to show a pop up dialog box...